# Can I ask licencing questions regarding stock photography on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I presume the answer to this must be no, but I thought I'd ask seeing as there is a [licensing](/questions/tagged/licensing) tag, but I guess that must relate to software not to graphics. If that's the case then where would be the best place to ask?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you can't.

Licensing of photographs is off topic. Not a programming question.

[photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/) **may** be appropriate, but don't post before reading their FAQ.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like they have licensing questions there. Looks like a runner.